# Classification Based Collaborative Filtering Model

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, predictive-modeling, data-science-model, multiclass-classification

I was going through algorithms for collaborative filtering-based prediction. Most of the places, I read about using matrix factorization based on ratings of the likeness of the user. But for my use case, I have to predict on the bases of classified data. For example, I have a list of user who orders from place1,place2, etc and they mostly get their items delivered to address1,address2 etc. Initially, I thought to give binary ratings to the places, but I am having multiple criteria i.e addresses and places. How can I use collaborative filtering in this case?

| User | Place | Delivery Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | X | A |
| One | X | A |
| One | Y | C |
| Two | Y | C |
| Two | Z | B |
| Three | Y | ?? |

Comment: What are you trying to predict?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your objective here is not clear.
Following your example, I belive you want to obtain likeness/relationship between users and places.

So basically what you would want to do is to create a domain of users and places. Now for different addresses (eg. A and C), you can treat the same user (eg. One) as different users i.e. "One-A" and "One-C". You can now assign a binary value for each "user-address" v/s "place". Then you can use any collaborative filtering method to get the affinity of the users corresponding to a particular address, for a particular ordering place.